# Executable Python Zip with C extensions

Tags: python

I have a zip file with a `__main__.py` that executes fine: ./myapp

But inside of this zip, there is a C extension library.so file that must be loaded but this library.so file is not being found.

If I execute the directory (without zipping it), it executes correctly. So it appears the C extensions are not supported or is some configuration issue. Any ideas?

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0441/

Comment: One not-simple question that is not easily found in Google should be perfect for StackOverFlow. It would great to people stopping downvotes  for no good reason. At least give some useful comment after doing this.

Answer (score 4):

C extensions cannot be loaded from `.zip` libraries. This is a limitation outside of Python's control.

This already applied to [`zipimport` support](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html):

> Any files may be present in the ZIP archive, but only files .py and .py[co] are available for import. ZIP import of dynamic modules (.pyd, .so) is disallowed.

Comment: Do you know if there is any workaround for this? I was thinking about putting the .SO files in an specific directory and then try loading them with pkg_resources.

Comment: You will indeed have to put them in a separate directory, that is added to `sys.path`. Perhaps you could extract them to a temporary directory whenever the `__main__` module is run?